# MongoDB Query Array of Objects within Array of Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm very new to the mongoDB scene and I'm trying to figure out the best way to return a bottom level object that is within an array that is contained in an object that is in an array of objects. I know that sounds confusing so let me show you what I am working with.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58b833a04953db3dd302102b"),
    "team": "Dragons",
    "rosters": [{
        "season": "2016-17",
        "players": [{
            "pitcher": "Oliver queen"
        }, {
            "catcher": "Slade Wilson"
        }]
    }, {
        "season": "2015-16",
        "players": [{
            "pitcher": "Joker"
        }, {
            "catcher": "Batman"
        }]
    }]
}
```

So my end goals are:

1. Display a single player, based on their position (i.e 'pitcher'), for a specific season for a specific team. For example I want to know who the pitcher was for season 2015-16 for the dragons team.
2. Display ALL players, based on their position, for all seasons for the team Dragons.
3. Update the name for a specific player in a specific season for a specific team. (Example, update "pitcher" in season 2016-17 for the Dragons from "Oliver Queen" to "Green Arrow"

Is this even a plausible query to build? If not, where could I fix my data model to be more performant?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple nested array in your collections and in MongoDB you can't use multiple [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to perform update operation on your players collection. And you should define a `name` field and a `role` field for your players. You could structure your data like the following :

### Team / Season document

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58b99f08a7a2dfe1174e8eb9"),
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "players": [{
        "name": "Oliver queen",
        "role": "pitcher"
    }, {
        "name": "SomeOne",
        "role": "pitcher"
    }, {
        "name": "Slade Wilson",
        "role": "catcher"
    }]
}
```

So you will have one document per unique team/season pair, so :

- 1st document : `Dragons/2016-17`
- 2nd document : `Dragons/2015-17`
- etc...

> Display a single player, based on their position (i.e 'pitcher'), for
>   a specific season for a specific team. For example I want to know who
>   the pitcher was for season 2015-16 for the dragons team.

_ If you have only one player by role use :

```
db.players.find({
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "players.role": "pitcher"
}, { "players.$": 1 })
```

It will return only the first player matching the `pitcher` role :

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("58b99f08a7a2dfe1174e8eb9"), "players": [{ "name": "Oliver queen", "role": "pitcher" }] }
```

_ If you can have multiple player by role (like in the model above), use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the `players` array with the matching role :

```
db.players.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "team": "Dragons",
        "season": "2016-17",
        "players.role": "pitcher"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        players: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$players",
                as: "player",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$player.role", "pitcher"] }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

That gives you :

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("58b99f08a7a2dfe1174e8eb9"), "players": [{ "name": "Oliver queen", "role": "pitcher" }, { "name": "SomeOne", "role": "pitcher" }] }
```

> Display ALL players, based on their position, for all seasons for the
>   team Dragons.

Use an aggregation grouping by `players.role` :

```
db.players.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "team": "Dragons"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$players"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$players.role",
        players: {
            $push: "$players.name"
        }
    }
}])
```

That gives :

```
{ "_id": "catcher", "players": ["Slade Wilson", "Batman"] } { "_id": "pitcher", "players": ["Oliver queen", "SomeOne", "Joker"] }
```

> Update the name for a specific player in a specific season for a
>   specific team. (Example, update "pitcher" in season 2016-17 for the
>   Dragons from "Oliver Queen" to "Green Arrow"

Update with [positional parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) matching the item found :

```
db.players.update({
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "players.name": "Oliver queen"
}, {
    $set: {
        "players.$.name": "Green Arrow"
    }
});
```

### Team / Season / Player document

```
{
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "name": "Oliver queen",
    "role": "pitcher"
}, {
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "name": "SomeOne",
    "role": "pitcher"
}, {
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "name": "Slade Wilson",
    "role": "catcher"
}
```

Each document features a player in a specific team, in a specific season

> Display a single player, based on their position (i.e 'pitcher'), for
>   a specific season for a specific team. For example I want to know who
>   the pitcher was for season 2015-16 for the dragons team.

```
db.players.find({ "team": "Dragons", "season": "2016-17", "role": "pitcher" })
```

> Display ALL players, based on their position, for all seasons for the
>   team Dragons.

```
db.players.find({"team": "Dragons", "role": "pitcher"})
```

> Update the name for a specific player in a specific season for a
>   specific team. (Example, update "pitcher" in season 2016-17 for the
>   Dragons from "Oliver Queen" to "Green Arrow"

```
db.players.update({
    "team": "Dragons",
    "season": "2016-17",
    "name": "Oliver queen"
}, {
    $set: {
        "name": "Green Arrow"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the VERY detailed response! I'm still trying to shake out the relational thinking when building my schemas. I will use the new structure you posted and keep it as a reference for myself in the future to not make the same mistake again.

Comment: Note that you can also use 1 document per unique `team`/`season`/`player` if you prefer, this way you don't have any array, and it's easier to perform find, update, insert, no `$unwind` required etc... I can add this solution to the post if you want

Comment: If you wouldn't mind adding it. I might be able to figure it out on my own but it never hurts to have the answer sheet to look at just in case. Will the performance be noticeably better with the `team/season/player` document set-up creating a larger amount of documents as opposed to the array set-up?

Comment: I think it would be better to find in your collection with a `find` query rather than an `aggregate`. If you want to have more nested fields in `players` it will also be more easier to use filters and update nested elements inside players if you want to add some later. But you can keep on the model with players array if it's ok

Comment: I've updated my post, note that with the last model there is no need to use aggregation especially for `find`